# Как получить позицию элемента на странице

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

Здравствуйте! Сразу к вопросу: есть фреймы, в каждом фрейме есть свои элементы. Как можно получить координаты этих элементов относительно всей страницы? У меня получается получить позиции внутри самих фреймов, но не получается получить позиции относительно всей страницы.

Comment: а как насчет получить позицию нужного фрейма и добавить значения, которые Вы получили для элемента внутри этого фрейма?

Comment: @ZoltanToth а как можно это сделать? Если найти элемент во фрейме,   то не получается после из него выйти.

Comment: контент фрейма свой или туда подгружается какая-то страница с другого сайта/домена?

Comment: @ZoltanToth отдельным файлом подгружается.

Answer (score 0):

можешь написать функцию, которая будет получать положение фрейма, относительно документа, и положение элемента во фрейме, и возвращать сумму этих значений